# Display different indices depending on the scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `Orders` index page with two links, whose indices I want to filter by the status of the order:

```
<%= link_to "Current Orders", orders_path(:by_status => "processing") %>
...
<%= link_to "Past Orders", orders_path(:by_status => "completed") %>
```

My controller looks like:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  has_scope :by_status

  def index
    case params[:status]
    when "completed"
      @past_orders = Order.where(status: "completed")
    when "processing"
      @current_orders = Order.where(status: "processing")
    end
  end
end
```

I'm sure `def index` is the main problem. But I also can't figure out how to display that in the view page. I have:

```
<% @past_orders.each do |order| %>
```

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem you can split the render based of your condition from index.html.erb

in index.html.erb create condition if @post_orders has contents then render past_orders else render current_order

```
  <% if @post_orders %>
    <%= render 'past_order.html.erb' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'current_order.html.erb' %>
  <% end %>
```

then you create two partial file with name _past_order.html.erb and _current_order.html.erb put in same folder with index.html.erb

Comment: Thanks, My only problem with this is that when using "if @past_orders has contents"  and I click on the Current Orders link it won't display the current orders. My goal is to be able to display the results depending on which link I click on..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the view to look the same for both scopes then you should handle it at the controller. It looks like you're using the `has_scope` gem, so this should work:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  has_scope :by_status, only: :index

  def index
    @orders = apply_scopes(Order)
  end
end
```

You need to have a matching scope method on the `Order` model

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  scope :by_status, ->(status) { where status: status }
end
```

In your view **`orders/index.html.erb`** you would handle the collection exactly the same way, using `@orders` for both current and past orders

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
```

If you ever need to display a component of the view differently depending on the order status just add an `if` statement

```
<% if order.status == "completed" >
  <p>Something<p>
<% else >
  <p>Something else<p>
<% end >
```